# Sort firebase object based on time stamp

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am developing chat application using Firebase. In my chat application i have chat Inbox.I need to sort the inbox chat based on time stamp.

To load the object from Firebase i am using following code:

```
var chatwith = new Firebase(firbaseUrl+'/chatInbox/'+$scope.userId);
     var list = $firebaseArray(chatwith);
     list.$loaded().then(function() {
         $scope.dataList = list;
         $scope.dataLength = $scope.dataList.length;
         if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();

     });
```

I need to sort the  `$scope.dataList` object based on the time stamp. is it possible?

Please suggest

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question

> I need to sort the  $scope.dataList object based on the time stamp. is it possible?

yes it's possible , you could use orderByChild like this

```
var chatwith = new Firebase(firbaseUrl+'/chatInbox/'+$scope.userId);
chatwith = chatwith.orderByChild('NAME_OF_THE_FIELD_TIMESTAMP');
     var list = $firebaseArray(chatwith);
     list.$loaded().then(function() {
         $scope.dataList = list;
         $scope.dataLength = $scope.dataList.length;
         if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
     });
```

just don't forget to Defin Data Indexes on production like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "chatInbox": {
      ".indexOn": ["NAME_OF_THE_FIELD_TIMESTAMP", "OTHER_FIELD"]
    }
  }
}
```